# How to get Version from shadow element in Javers

Tags: java, audit, javers

I am trying to get version from shadows in the Javers.

Currently getting through this way. is this the correct implementation, I think this method can hamper performance a little bit. I am pasting the code here

```
    List<Shadow<Season>> shadows= javers.findShadows(QueryBuilder.byInstance(optionalSeason.get()).build());

    for (Shadow<Season> shadow : shadows) {
     List<CdoSnapshot> changes=javers.findSnapshots(QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(id,Season.class).withCommitId(shadow.getCommitId()).build());

     changes.get(0).getVersion()
                  }
```

If there is any better way, please let me know, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good question, looks like you can't get it easily because this information is missing in `Shadow` class:

```java
public class Shadow<T> {
    private final CommitMetadata commitMetadata;
    private final T it;
```

Since each `Shadow` is created from one `CdoSnapshot`, `Shadow` class can be easily extended to:

```java
public class Shadow<T> {
    private final CdoSnapshot snapshot;
    private final T it;
```

You can contribute this change to Javers if you want.